# How to get xml response with Jsp Page

Tags: java, javascript, xml, jsp

Need to show xml response with jsp page. I am getting Object of xml object"vehicleOrderResponse", If I will show this object in new file then xml is showing successfully, but not getting xml data in jsp page. Provide any piece of code to show xml response in jsp page?

Written code:

```
 try
    {
        SAMSServiceAdaptor serviceadaptor = new SAMSServiceAdaptor();
        VehicleOrderDetailRequestType vehicleOrderDetailRequest = serviceadaptor.createRequest(
                vin, bodyCode, dealerCode, ordernumber, modelYear);
        vehicleOrderResponse = SAMSServiceLocator.getSAMSServicePort().retrieveVehicleOrderDetail(vehicleOrderDetailRequest);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                    .newInstance(VehicleOrderDetailResponseType.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,
                    true);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        marshaller.marshal(vehicleOrderResponse, bytes);
        String sb = new String(bytes.toByteArray());
        String responseXML = sb.trim();
        if(responseXML!=null){
            out.println(responseXML.trim().substring("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>".length()));    
        }else{
                out.println("Response was null, Please check input paramters! ");
            }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        out.println(ex.toString());
    }
```

Getting XMl Response in format:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:VehicleOrderDetailResponseType xmlns="urn:ford/interface/VehicleOrder/UnitDetail/v2" xmlns:ns2="urn:ford/VehicleOrder/UnitDetail/v2.0">
    <Orders>
        <ModelYear>2014</ModelYear>
        <Dealer>13058</Dealer>
        <Body>P8J</Body>
        <ItemNo>445S  </ItemNo>
        <Vin>1ZVBP8JZ3E5223527</Vin>
        <Division>F                             </Division>
        <GsdbSiteCode>G9W1A</GsdbSiteCode>
        <CurrentBuildWeek>2013-04-01Z</CurrentBuildWeek>
        <ReceiptDate>2013-03-07Z</ReceiptDate>
        <VehicleLineDescription>Mustang</VehicleLineDescription>
```

Comment: I think you should go read through this tutorial http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use two different forms with different ids and call the respective submit function based on submit event of the respective form??